# jquery datepicker and custom validation

Tags: jquery-ui, validation, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to add custom validation(I think) for validating input from an user. Here's my use case:
I'm using the jquery ui datepicker for selecting dates, with localization like this:

`$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ currentLocale ] );`

I use the bassistance validation plugin, and using rules for `date:true` and such does not work with different formats(or if they do please tell me how!). So I've made my own date validation methods like this

```
   $.validator.addMethod("validDate", function(value) {
        return parseDateString(value) != null;
    }, jQuery.validator.messages.date);
```

This all works very well except for the fact when selecting a date in the datepicker the validation is fired before the value of the componet is changed! So I actually validate the previous value....

Does anyone have a solution for me?
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could trigger validation [upon the user closing](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose) the `datepicker` popup:

```
$("#birthdate").datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        /* Validate a specific element: */
        $("form").validate().element("#birthdate");
    }
});
```

Using `validate`'s [`element()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element) function will enable you to validate a particular field immediately.

I've created an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/3Yvpe/) in which any date who's year != 2011 will trigger failed validation.

Comment: Another way to use this onClose approach is for validating a dynamic datepicker. If the page is finished loading, and then an input element is added with the datepicker attached, the validation message will be slightly out of sync. If the user attempts to post without choosing a date the message appears. Upon choosing the date in this scenario, the message will not be removed (unless the date is chosen a second time). `onClose: function(){ $(this).valid();}` will cause the message to be properly in sync.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, but I have been stuck for a couple of days with a strange issuue.

I have two date pickers with custom validation and the method above works great. I then, through a JavaScript function, added two more, and the validation only fired every other time.

Looking around I found this (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7451), and so in my onClose event added (altered to match the above example) after the validate:

$("form #birthdate").trigger("blur");

And now it works.