# jQuery UI Datepicker with altfields: Validation not firing when it should

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 3 datepickers (startdate, enddate and duedate) on my form and the dates that are picked are printed in their respective altfields. I have the date validation rules setup to validate the values in the altfields and not the datepickers themselves (I tried validating on the datepickers but it did nothing).

The only rules are the they are required and that the enddate and duedate must be greater than the startdate.

If I pick an endate or duedate that is equal to the startdate I don't get any validation errors as expected until I click the submit button or if I give focus to the altfield then click away (focus lost).

Is there a way to manually validate these inputs when a date is selected in the datepicker?

Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FWudz/)

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">    
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
    <title>Goals</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../style/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.css"
    />
    <script src="../include/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-size: 96%;
        }
        label {
            width: 10em;
            float: left;
        }
        label.error {
            float: none;
            color: red;
            padding-left: .5em;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        p {
            clear: both;
        }
        .submit {
            margin-left: 12em;
        }
        em {
            font-weight: bold;
            padding-right: 1em;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
        .ui-widget {
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        .ui-slider-horizontal {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30em;
        }
        .ui-slider-vertical {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            margin: 0em 2em 1em 0em;
        }
    </style>
    <form id="newusergoal" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Add a New Goal</legend>
            <label for="startdate">Start Date:</label>
            <br/>
            <div id="startdateselect"></div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="startdate" id="startdate" readonly="true" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label for="enddate">End Date:</label>
            <br/>
            <div id="enddateselect"></div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="enddate" id="enddate" readonly="true" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <label for="duedate">Due Date:</label>
            <br/>
            <div id="duedateselect"></div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name="duedate" id="duedate" readonly="true" />
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save New Goal" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#newusergoal").validate({
    rules: {
        startdate: {
            required: true
        },
        enddate: {
            required: true,
            greaterThan: "#startdate"
        },
        duedate: {
            required: true,
            greaterThan: "#startdate"
        }
    },
messages: {
    startdate: {
        required: "Goal must have a start date"
    },
    enddate: {
        required: "Goal must have an end date",
        greaterThan: "End date must be greater than the start date"
    },
    duedate: {
        required: "Goal must have an due date",
        greaterThan: "Due date must be greater than the start date"
    }
}
});

$("#startdateselect").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "10Y",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField: "#startdate"
});
$("#enddateselect").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "10Y",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField: "#enddate"
});
$("#duedateselect").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: "10Y",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    altField: "#duedate"
});

jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    "greaterThan",

function (value, element, params) {
    if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
        return new Date(value) > new Date($(params).val());
    }

    return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) || (Number(value) > Number($(params).val()));
},
    'Must be greater than {0}.');

});
```

Comment: Please strip your code down to the bare minimum required to show the problem and construct a jsFiddle demo.  What do you mean by "manually" validate?

Comment: jsfiddle demo is on the way, please stand by.

Comment: Please review how your jsFiddle is constructed.  You do not put the `<head>` section into the HTML pane, only the `body` contents.  The external files get included on the left panel and the CSS gets inserted into the CSS pane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Quote OP**:  "Is there a way to manually validate these inputs... ?"

Use `.element()` to programmatically trigger a validation test on a single element.

```
$("#myform").validate().element("#myfield");
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/element#element

**Demo**:  http://jsfiddle.net/vMNsy/

This demo shows how `.element()` is used to trigger a validation test on the first field on the DOM ready event.  You can call it with your own custom event or function.

See this answer for something more specific...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4635640/594235

```
$("#myfield").datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        $("myform").validate().element("#myfield");
    }
});
```

**Edit**:  As per comments, `onClose` event is not applicable to OP, but leaving code in place for the benefit of others.

Comment: call element() on datepicker close http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4634118/jquery-datepicker-and-custom-validation/4635640#4635640

Comment: Thanks @politus.  Adding this to the answer.

Comment: @Sparky - thanks for your patience and replying again. Your solution works. The other solution (onClose) does not work in my case because I'm displaying the calendar inline (called on a div instead of an input).

Comment: @John, I'm glad to hear it.  I'll just leave the `onclose` code in my answer for the benefit of others.